# How to split a dataframe then merge to see matches?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I need to find matches and mismatches of Level + Part for the Names. If the Part and the Level of a Name are the same for another Name, it is a match. What I'm thinking is, split the df to separate frames. One per name. then concat the frames together on a groupby(["Level", "Part"]). The problem is, I wont always have the same amount of names. Some datasheets will have 3, some will have 8. Is this the best way to go about this? If there's a better way, please let me know. I'm still learning.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':["A","ABC","A","ABC","ABC","AAB","AAB"] ,'Level': [1,1,2,1,3,4,2],'Part':["Upper","Upper 2","Upper 2","Upper","Middle", "Deck", "Ceiling"]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Part':["Upper","Upper 2","Middle", "Deck", "Ceiling"],'A Level': [1,2,"NaN","NaN","NaN"],'ABC Level': [1,1,3,"NaN","NaN"],'AAB Level': ["NaN","NaN","NaN",4,2]})

    Name    Level   Part
0   A         1     Upper
1   ABC       1     Upper 2
2   A         2     Upper 2
3   ABC       1     Upper
4   ABC       3     Middle
5   AAB       4     Deck
6   AAB       2     Ceiling
```

I want it to look something like this, but if there's a better output format, let me know.

```
    Part     A Level    ABC Level   AAB Level
0   Upper    1          1           NaN
1   Upper 2  2          1           NaN
2   Middle   NaN        3           NaN
3   Deck     NaN        NaN         4
4   Ceiling  NaN        NaN         2
```

Comment: Can you please provide the output so that it could be easy to get to that. Sample output for the above data is good to have. I am finding the question is lacking in giving me a vision of what you are asking.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know, I added an output that I think would best show the matches and mismatches.

Comment: Can you explain, how did the second row `ABC level` column got the `value 1`?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to edit the original df, I added one more row. It's fixed now.

Comment: Thank you for the correction, Have you solved it? If no, I'll try to wrote a chunk of code to handle this.

Comment: Not solved it but, I've made progress, but I think I'm doing it in a complicated way. I split the data into frames. One frame per name. put those frames in a list of frames. Now I'm trying to figure out a way to merge them together to have the rows side by side. I'm assuming I've to use a groupby somewhere. I basically need to show per part, what level is it in for A, ABC and AAB if these names do have that part. If you could help me with this it would be great!

Comment: I have posted my answer using pivot table below, hope it may help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the fucntion `.duplicated()` which returns True if there are 2 identical rows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':["A","A","ABC","ABC","AAB","AAB"] 
        ,'Level': [1,2,1,3,4,2]
        ,'Part':["Upper","Upper 2","Upper","Middle", "Deck", "Ceiling"]})

df['match'] = df.iloc[:,[1,2]].duplicated(keep=False)

print(df)
```

`.iloc()` is being used since you are interested in only the second and third columns. 
`keep=False` implies that it will return True on all appearances of the duplicate.

Output:

```
  Name  Level     Part  match
0    A      1    Upper   True
1    A      2  Upper 2  False
2  ABC      1    Upper   True
3  ABC      3   Middle  False
4  AAB      4     Deck  False
5  AAB      2  Ceiling  False
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I should've mentioned, I do need to show the matches and mismatches. I put an example of the kind of output I'm looking for. I will see if I can use the duplicated function to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

A PivotTable is an interactive way to quickly summarize large amounts of data. We can use the `pandas.pivot_table()` function to do this task.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Name':["A","ABC","A","ABC","ABC","AAB","AAB"], 
        'Level': [1,1,2,1,3,4,2],
        'Part':["Upper","Upper 2","Upper 2","Upper","Middle", "Deck", "Ceiling"]
    }
)

print(df)


# pivot table
table = pd.pivot_table(df, values='Level', index=['Part'],
                    columns=['Name'], aggfunc=np.sum, fill_value=0)

table.sort_values("Part", inplace=True, ascending=False)

print(table)
```

The above code will give the pivot table as follow,

```
Name     A  AAB  ABC
Part

Upper 2  2    0    1
Upper    1    0    1
Middle   0    0    3
Deck     0    4    0
Ceiling  0    2    0
```